# Bound on the distance in cartesian products

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a finite set in  $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Let 
\begin{align}
d=\min_{\substack{a,b \in S \\ a \neq b}} \| a-b\|
\end{align}
where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Eucleadian distance. In other words $d$ is the smallest distance between points of $S$.

Next let
\begin{align}
S_n= S \times \cdots \times S
\end{align}
that is $S_n$ is a Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $S$.

My question: can we give a bound on minimum distance of $S_n$ defined as
\begin{align}
d_n= \min_{\substack{a,b \in S_n \\ a \neq b}} \| a-b\|
\end{align}

in terms of $n$ and $d$.

I think in general we have that $d_n=d$ but I don't know how to show it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 
$$|x_i|^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2 \Rightarrow |x_i|\leq \|x\|_2 \Rightarrow\|x\|_\infty\leq\|x\|_2$$
for $a,b\in S_n$, $a\neq b$, you can get
$$\|a-b\|_2 \geq \|a-b\|_\infty = \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |a_i-b_i| \geq d,$$
since there is at least one $i$ where $a_i\neq b_i$. As the above inequality is true for all such pairs, you get $d_n\geq d$.

On the other hand choose $a,b\in S$ such that $|a-b|=d$. Then for $c_1,\ldots, c_{n-1}\in S$ you get
$$\|(c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1},a)-(c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1},b)\|_2 = |a-b|=d$$
which implies $d_n\leq d$.
Combining the inequalities finally yields $d_n=d$.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you another question? Suppose we have two finite sets: $S_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with minimum  $d_1$ and  $S_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with minimum  $d_2$. Is it correct that $d_{S_1 \times S_2} \ge \min(d_1,d_2)$ ?

Comment: @Boby: I think so. Doesn't this follow from the estimate $\|a-b\|_\infty = \max \{|a_1-b_1|,|a_2-b_2|\} \geq \min \{d_1,d_2\}$? If this is true you would even get the maximum of $d_1$ and $d_2$ instead of the minimum.